# Regex for allowing two numbers(0-9) anywhere in the charecters

Tags: regex

I am new newbie to regex world,and i am trying to get regex for the following....

A user can have in the following manner

1. goodyzain
2. 1goodyzain
3. goody1zain
4. goodyzain1
5. goodyzain19
6. 1goodyzain9

...etc

The user can have max of two integer numbers b/w 0-9 in the name...i tried following regex...

```
(?:\d{0,2}+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,2})|[a-zA-Z]
```

works fine for case 1,4,5 but fails for others....a help will be appreciable...:)

Comment: For every regex question, you need to have a sample text and sample match that you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){0,2}[a-zA-Z]*$
```

Comment: its works cool,but where are we telling in regex there should be only two numbers(0-9)....???just currious

Comment: That's what `{0,2}`. It says that the group before that can appear 0-2 times. Since the group only contains 1 digit, and the group can appear at most 2 times, there can only be 2 numbers.

Comment: no the previous one...:)  ^[a-zA-Z]*\d?[a-zA-Z]*\d?[a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: That one only has 2 `\d`, so there can only be 2 numbers. they're both optional, so it allows fewer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the negative pattern:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $string );
```

and then count the **$output** length, if you have >2 then it's a wrong format

```
if (2 > preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string)) {
    // ok
} else {
    // not ok, more than 2 digits
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!([a-zA-Z]*?\d){3,})^[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

This works.See demo.Uses a negative lookahead.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/7